# SVN to deployable folder

Tags: tortoisesvn, web-deployment

I have an SVN repository on my server(windows-7) and my application is runnin on Tomcat.
On server every time i check out my application(which was committed from different machines) and then manually place the files in webapps folder to deploy the app onto tomcat.
Is there a way where i can set up a svn linking with webapps folder, wherein whenever the users commit there code it should be directly deployed on to tomcat webapps folder.

Answer (score 0):

This question comes up often enough that it's in the [FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#website-auto-update)

Aside from doing it strictly via a hook script (which requires admin-level access to the repository, on the repository server), you can set up a Continuous Integration server to monitor the repository and perform your deployments that way.